# How to do a useEffect() style ajax call after button press in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, use-effect, react-native-button

I'm new to React and React Native.
Trying to build a simple app that does an API call on the press of a button.

My code below works but just doesn't "look right" to me.
useEffect() is run after the page loads? Seems to be run multiple times.
I'm counting button clicks as true and then have an if statement inside useEffect. Does that mean the app is constantly checking if the button is pressed?

I tried putting useEffect() inside the getJoke() function but react native didn't like it.
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

If I put getJoke() inside useEffect() it calls the api constantly. I jet api response after response after response.

**I just want one button press to result in one API call, and the text below the button to be updated like in AJAX if this was a webpage.**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 const [data, setData] = useState();
 const [ error, setError ] = useState(false);
 const [buttonPress, setButtonPress] = useState(false);

 const getJoke = async () => {
  try {
   const response = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
   const json = await response.json();
   console.log(json);
   console.log('Joke: ' + json.value);
   setData(json.value);   // Chuck API provides joke in "value" field. Only saving the joke.

  // Unfortunately you can't call hooks useEffect from here?

 } catch (error) {
   console.error(error);
   setError(true);       
 } finally {
   setLoading(false);
 }
}

// Constant api calls if I do this
 /*
 useEffect(() => {
  getJoke();
 });
 */

 useEffect(() => {
   // Check if button has been pressed, if so update the page
   if(buttonPress){
    getJoke();
    setButtonPress(false);
   }
 });

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
   <Text>Press button to get a random joke:</Text>
   <Button title="Joke" onPress={setButtonPress}/>
  
   <Text>{data}</Text>
  
  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good use case for effects. Loading on button press is something you could do will plain old functions. But the answers below address what may happen if you tried anyway. Effects are supposed to automatically react to changed in your state environment (either properties passed in or local useState states).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runs after every rendering

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs after EVERY rendering
  });
```

runs once after the initial rendering.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
  }, []);
```

runs only when any dependency value changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
```

So, I think you should do like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Check if button has been pressed, if so update the page
   if(buttonPress){
    getJoke();
    setButtonPress(false);
   }
}, [buttonPress]);
```

And the reason for the Invalid hook call is there are few [rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detailed explanation. Yeah, the "hooks" in react were getting me a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all your `useEffect` block and replace with `useEffect` below

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // Check if button has been pressed, if so update the page
   if(buttonPress){
    getJoke();
    setButtonPress(false);
   }
}, [buttonPress]);
```

Basically how `useEffect` works is that, by introducing second parameter, we are saying, run `useEffect` only when value of `buttonPress` has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this answer is correct.